# How to increase disk space and memory limits for docker using console?

Tags: docker

I easily managed to do this on the desktop version of Docker via preferences, but how can I do this using console on a remote linux server?

Answer (score 1):

The limits you are configuring in the Docker Desktop UI are on the embedded Linux VM. All containers run within that VM, giving you an upper limit on the sum of all containers. To replicate this on a remote Linux server, you would set the physical hardware or VM constraints to match your limit.

For individual containers, you can specify the following:

- `--cpus` to set the CPU shares allocated to the cgroup. This can be something like `2.5` to allocate up to 2.5 CPU threads to the container. Containers attempting to use more CPU will be throttled.
- `--memory` or `-m` to set the memory limit in bytes. This is applied to the cgroup the container runs within. Containers attempting to exceed this limit will be killed.

Disk space for containers and images is controlled by the disk space available to /var/lib/docker for the default overlay2 graph driver. You can limit this by placing the directory under a different drive/partition with limited space. For volume mounts, disk space is limited by where the volume mount is sourced, and the default named volumes go back to /var/lib/docker.